# Bootstrap table not working good with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div ng-controller="reportCtrl">
      <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead class="row col-md-3">
              <tr class="row">
                  <th class="col-md-6">Key </th>
                  <th class="col-md-6"> Value</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="param in params" class="row col-md-3">
              <tr class="row">
                  <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.key}}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.val}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

I have this table, when i'm using the bootstrap grid system with ng-repeat the results are very strange..
[image: my Table]

I've tried to play with the grid system but it dosent seem that it helps..

Comment: Try your code without using bootstrap class.  I think the problem may be `class="row col-md-3"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **do not need** to add the `row col-md-3` classes to the `table-body` or the `row` class to the `tr` elements. Also if you are repeating the items your `ng-repeat` needs to be on the `tr` element, if it is on the `tbody` element you are going to have multiple unnecessary `tbody` elements.

Please see working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/tn3o6sta/2/)

If you just want a simple table:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Key </th>
        <th> Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
}])
```

If you do not need the `table element` you can use the bootstrap `row` and `col-*` classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1>Key</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1>Value</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      {{$index}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the class="row .."

```
<div ng-controller="reportCtrl">
      <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Key </th>
                  <th> Value</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="param in params">
              <tr>
                  <td>{{param.key}}</td>
                  <td>{{param.val}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: but then the table appears in full width i want it to be small table

Comment: An easy hack is to encapsulate the the whole table within grid. `<div class="row><div class="col-md-6"><table ....</table></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Remove the bootstrap classes row, col-md-6 in tbody  ,use the below code.. 
 for all medias, it will be resized 

<div ng-controller="reportCtrl" class="table-responsive>
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Key </th>
              <th> Value</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="param in params">
          <tr>
              <td>{{param.key}}</td>
              <td>{{param.val}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="reportCtrl">
  <table class="table table-hover">
     <div class="row col-md-3">
      <thead class="row">
          <tr>
              <th class="col-md-6">Key </th>
              <th class="col-md-6"> Value</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="param in params">
          <tr class="row">
              <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.key}}</td>
              <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.val}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </div>
  </table>
```

I have made few changes, like covered the entire table into 3 divisions and then
dividing them further into 6-6 for ths and tds. Just see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code
By removing the `col-md-3`
and style the table with `width:auto`

```
<div ng-controller="reportCtrl">
  <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto">
    <thead class="row ">
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-md-6">Key </th>
        <th class="col-md-6"> Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="param in params" class="row ">
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.key}}</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.val}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-repeat="param in params" class="row ">
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.key}}</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 info">{{param.val}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```